# login details(id,password) visible in plain text in browser developer tools

Tags: http, security, https, web, developer-tools

I am particularly new to security in websites.The day before, I logged in to my college website via my roll number, password and a captcha code. When I opened the developer tools on Mozilla, I could see one Post request (my details) being sent over the network.

I studied in my college course that there are 2 ways to send these type of details to a server. One is via URL arguments and other is through the http parameters. I clicked on the parameter tab of this POST request and I see the my login details in plain text like this :

- LoginId -
- Password -
- Captcha - .......

Does it mean that these details are being sent as it is? or these details are only visible to me? Forgive me if it's too lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Does it mean that these details are being sent as it is?"*

It depends. **If the request is sent through HTTP, yes. If the request is sent through HTTPS, no.**

You can install a proxy such as [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to observe. When the login request is sent through HTTP, the request URL and body are all visible, which means if someone is sniffing packets on internet, he/she can easily see your login id and password. It's visible to everyone.

When the login request is sent through HTTPS, however, in Charles the request URL would be "unknown" and the request body would be a bunch of unreadable code (encrypted). It indicates that even if someone is sniffing, it's impossible to steal valuable information. It's only visible to you.